# Locate a number in an array with ascending even and descending odd entries

Tags: matlab

Below are two examples of arrays I have, with some given `length`:

[image]

For some value `z`, I want to find the column the value is in. MATLAB code I wrote:

```
if z == 1
   column = ceil(length/2);   
elseif logical(mod(z,2))
   column = length - (z-3)/2;
else
   column = z/2;
end
```

It is correct I think. But ugly and possibly slow. Is there a one-liner in MATLAB that can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's call the array `x`:

```
x = 2 4 6 8 1 9 7 5 3
```

I'm assuming you don't have the array stored in a variable (in which case this question boils down do: `find(x==z)`), and that you don't need the array either (in which case this question is really: "How do I create `x`?").

---

First off:

**Don't use `length` as a variable name**. `length` is a builtin function, and overloading it is a bad idea. Although it's better to use the builtin `numel` instead of `length`, overloading `length` is not a good idea. It might cause all sorts of strange bugs. Choose another variable name (I'll use `len`, you might use something else).

---

`x` has a fairly straight forward setup, and can be created quite simply using concatenation and the colon operator.

```
x = [2:2:len, 1, fliplr(3:2:len)]
```

If you can guarantee that `len` is odd then it's simply:

```
x = [2:2:len, 1, len:-2:3]
```

Now, you have `x`, and you know `z`. The only thing remaining is a simple call to `find`:

```
col = find(x==z);
```